# How can I integrate react-native-branch on React Native EXPO Managed Workflow and Bare Workflow project

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo, release-apk

I have created a **React Native** project using expo. And I am going to integrate `react-native-branch` for sharing referral codes with other users. But when I run the app on android, this error will caused:

```
null of object .... RNBranch.STANDARD_EVENT_ADD_TO_CART
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you

I tried to build using

```
expo run:android
```

It works on devices and emulators.

But when I use the release APK, the app is stacked, not crash.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to switch Managed Workflow and Bare Workflow project.
And then you can build release apk and debug apk using these command on terminal.

To build Debug APK:
"cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug"
To build Release APK:
"cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd .."
To build Release AAB:
"cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease && cd .."